# Question about Proof Involving Euclidean Spaces and Total Boundedness

Tags: real-analysis

$\bf\underline{Theorem:}$ Every bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^{k}$ is totally bounded.

$\bf\underline{Proof:}$

Suppose that $S$ is a bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^{k}$. To show that $S$ is totally bounded suppose that $\epsilon > 0$. Define $$\delta=\frac{\epsilon}{2\sqrt{k}}.$$ Define the set $M$ to be the set of all points $$y=\left(y_{1},y_{2},\ldots,y_{k}\right)$$ such that each coordinate $y_{j}$ is an integer multiple of $\delta$. 
Define the set $F=\{y\in M|B\left(y,\epsilon\right)\cap S\neq \emptyset\}$. Since $M$ is a bounded set we know that $F$ must be finite. Given any point $x\in M$ we know that there is a member $y\in M$ such that $$|x-y|\le \delta\sqrt{k}\le\frac{\epsilon}{2}< \epsilon$$ and such a point $y$ must belong to $F$. Therefore $$S\subseteq \bigcup_{y\in F} B\left(y,\epsilon\right)$$ and so $S$ is included in finitely many balls with radius $\epsilon$.

We have thus shown that the set $S$ is totally bounded. $\blacksquare$

What I’m unclear about is the choice for $\delta$ here. Why not just make $\delta = \frac{\epsilon}{2}$? What is the benefit of including the $\sqrt{k}$ in the denominator of $\delta$?

Comment: Because you want $|x-y|<\varepsilon$ not $|x-y|<\varepsilon\sqrt{k}$.

Comment: Okay, but where did the $\sqrt{k}$ even come from? Why does the inequality $|x-y|\leq \delta\sqrt{k}$ hold?

Comment: Try to compute diagonal of $k$ dimensional cube whos side is $\delta$

Comment: More simply, since each $y_i$ is an integer multiple of $\delta$, for any $x$, we can find a $y$ with $|x_i-y_i|<\delta$ for each $i=1,\dots,n$.

Comment: @Norbert: Okay, so the $sqrt{k}$ is the ratio of the length of the diagonal of a k-dimensional cube to the length of the side of said cube? So is the inequality $|x-y|\leq \delta\sqrt{k}$ basically saying "the distance between x and y cannot be more than the diagonal of each cube" since the longest distance in any cube is the diagonal? Sorry if I'm being dumb.

Thanks for the replies everyone!

Comment: @TedShifrin: TedShifrin: Okay I understand your inequality. However, I'm not sure if you mean that I should replace part of my proof with this or if you're just helping to explain where the $\sqrt{k}$ comes from?

Comment: @Euclid'sCompass yes

Comment: Yes. I was giving an alternative explanation if you didn't like thinking of geometrically in terms of cubes. If $|x_i-y_i|<\delta$ for each $i=1,\dots,k$, then $|x-y| = \left(\sum_{i=1}^k (x_i-y_i)^2\right)^{1/2}< \delta\sqrt k$.